# How to deploy a Controller class to production?

Tags: unit-test, deployment

Here we go.

- I need to deploy an Apex Class to production.
- I'm currently unable to do the default deploy on my production org.
- I thought on doing a specific test class to implement the class I need to deploy.
- I made the test class but Salesforce doesn't allow the method getContent to be called in a test class.

What do you guys suggest as a solution to this?

Edit1:

I do the deploys via Change Sets.
I can't do the default deploy because some other test classes are generating errors.
Apex class method that calls getContent I'm trying to deploy:
(It's gonna be a little bit frustrating for you to understand because it's not in English) [enviarEmail means sendEmail, if you're curious]

```
public void enviarEmail()
    {
            this.msg = '';
            System.debug('visita.Formularios__c ' + visita.Formularios_Respondidos__c);
            System.debug('Acordos_Respondidos__c ' + visita.Acordos_Respondidos__c);

            System.debug('visita.Tipo_checklist__c ' + visita.Tipo_checklist__c + ' - ' + permiteEnviarEmail);

            if (visita.ASVEN_Acesso__r.Usuario__r.IsActive) {
                this.blException = true;
                this.permiteEnviarEmail = false;
                this.msg = 'Só é possível encerrar a visita quando o ASVEN está ativo';
                return;
            }

            if(visita.Tipo_checklist__c == 'Recorrente' && permiteEnviarEmail)
            {
                    this.emailEnviado = BSEnviarEmailEncerramento.enviarEmailRecorrente(id);
                    System.debug(visita.Tipo_checklist__c);
                    return;
            }
            else if(permiteEnviarEmail)
            {

                    Id templateId;
                    String emailUsuario;
                    try
                    {
                            templateId = DAOEmailTemplate.obterTemplatePorNome('Fechamento_de_Visita').id;
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                            system.debug('Exception: ' + e + '\n' + e.getStackTraceString());
                            this.blException = true;
                            this.msg = 'Erro ao selecionar modelo de visita com nome Fechamento_de_Visita';
                            return;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                            emailUsuario = DAOUsuario.getEmailUsuario(UserInfo.getUserId());
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                            system.debug('Exception: ' + e + '\n' + e.getStackTraceString());
                            this.blException = true;
                            this.msg = 'E-mail do usuário inválido.';
                            return;
                    }

                    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/ResumoPDF?Id=' + this.Id);
                    Blob pageAsBlob;
                    try
                    {
                            pageAsBlob = pr.getContentAsPDF();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                            system.debug('Exception: ' + e + '\n' + e.getStackTraceString());
                            this.blException = true;
                            this.msg = 'Erro ao gerar PDF.';
                            return;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                            Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                            attach.setContentType('application/pdf');
                            attach.setFileName('Fechamento_visita_' + this.visita.Name + '.pdf');
                            attach.setInline(false);
                            attach.body = pageAsBlob;
                            System.debug('this.visita.ASVEN_Acesso__r.Usuario__c: ' + this.visita.ASVEN_Acesso__r.Usuario__c);
                            Messaging.Singleemailmessage mail = new Messaging.Singleemailmessage();
                            mail.setUseSignature(false);
                            mail.setCcAddresses(new list<string>{emailUsuario});
                            // mail.setWhatId(this.Id);
                            mail.setTargetObjectId(this.visita.ASVEN_Acesso__r.Usuario__c);
                            mail.setTemplateId(templateId);
                            mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attach });
                            mail.saveAsActivity = false;
                            enviarEmailGerentes(emailUsuario);
                            if(!this.blException)
                            {
                                    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Singleemailmessage[] { mail});
                                    this.visita.Email_Enviado__c = true;
                                    DAOVisita.atualizar(this.visita);
                                    this.emailEnviado = true;
                            }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                            system.debug('Exception: ' + e + '\n' + e.getStackTraceString());
                            this.blException = true;
                            this.msg = 'Erro ao enviar e-mail.\\nVerifique o e-mail do usuário Asven e o e-mail do usuário logado.';
                            return;
                    }

                    BSVisita.gerarCompromisso(this.visita);
            }
            else
            {
                            this.blException = true;
                            this.msg = 'Só é permitido o envio de e-mail quando todos os processos estiverem concluidos.';
                            return;
            }
}
```

Test class:

```
   @isTest(seeAllData=true)
    public class TestResumo {
        @isTest
        public static void testar() {
            Visita__c visita = [SELECT Id FROM Visita__c LIMIT 1];
            BSEnviarEmailEncerramento.enviarEmailApresentacao(visita.Id);
            BSEnviarEmailEncerramento.enviarEmailHibrido(visita.Id);
            BSEnviarEmailEncerramento.enviarEmailRecorrenteASVEN(visita.Id);
            BSEnviarEmailEncerramento.enviarEmailRecorrente(visita.Id);
            BSEnviarEmailEncerramento.enviarEmailRecorrenteApenasGerentes(visita.Id);
            CtrlResumo ctrl = new CtrlResumo(visita.Id);
            ctrl.getCompromissoResultado();
            ctrl.getFollowUpAsven();
            ctrl.getFollowUpAsven();
            ctrl.getResultadoAgencia();
            ctrl.salvar();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I usually deploy my Apex classes via a Change Set.  There's always a test class to go with the regular Apex class.  What is happening when you try to deploy to production?  Can you show us you code for the test class and regular Apex class?

Comment: Please include the code as you will need to get 75% or more test coverage and it is not possible to identify the problems without it.

Comment: That's the problem i can't achieve 75% code coverage because the method that calls getContent is too big and covers a lot of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work around the execution of `getContentAsPDF` in a test context by changing your PROD code to look like:

```
try
   {
    pageAsBlob = Test.isRunningTest() ? Blob.valueOf('foo') : pr.getContentAsPDF();
   }
```

Your testmethod isn't doing any asserts; just code coverage, which isn;t really testing all you need to test

*As an aside, you should avoid `seeAllData=true` at all costs as it creates deployment issues. Mock everything in the environment your code needs including custom settings.*

Comment: +1 for not using `seeAllData=true`!

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring your large method to make use of smaller static pure helper methods. A pure method is very easy to unit test because it uses only what is passed in as parameters. Here is a little more info on pure functions that while not written about apex give some great fundamental background on how to restructure code into smaller modules: https://www.sitepoint.com/functional-programming-pure-functions/.

Once you have lots of small modules in your code you an unit test each of these independently and easily achieve 75% coverage for your class. You can then use the "Run specified tests" option that it sounds like you are already familiar with to deploy the class and its tests to production.